# implementing IJsonSerializer for signalR alpha

Tags: signalr

just upgrading my application to SignalR alpha.  They have changed the IJsonSerializer interface

with the previous interface I had:

```
   public string Stringify(object obj)
    {
        var s = "";

            s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, _settings);

        return s;

    }
```

and it worked fine.

Now I am trying:

```
public class CustomJsonNetSerializer : IJsonSerializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings;

    public CustomJsonNetSerializer(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public object Parse(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    }

    public object Parse(string json, Type targetType)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, targetType);
    }

    public T Parse<T>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    public void Serialize(object value, System.IO.TextWriter writer)
    {
        var s = "";

            s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, _settings);

        writer.Write(s);

    }
}
```

but now no messages are getting sent back to the clients.

Edited following David's answer below - this is how I have implemented it - works now with the sample
The below code is of course pointless as it does what the default serialiser does - however I have removed my additions to do with locking objects for simplicity

public class CustomJsonNetSerializer : IJsonSerializer
    {

```
    JsonNetSerializer mySerialiser;
    public CustomJsonNetSerializer(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {         
        mySerialiser = new JsonNetSerializer(settings);
    }



    public void Serialize(object value, System.IO.TextWriter writer)
    {
            mySerialiser.Serialize(value, writer);                   
    }

    public object Parse(string json, Type targetType)
    {
        return mySerializer.Parse(json, targetType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the built in serializer (JsonNetSerializer). Also changing the case of the properties being serialized will break SignalR. We're working on that.